# I have two basic html form actions one going two "index.php" and the second going to "lookup.php"Can I do this?

Tags: php, html

I hope my question is clear. I got a small database that created and depending on what the user clicks it suppose to send the action to either index.php or lookup.php. Of course, this is not working.

```
 <h3>Please Click this to look up your Japanese Word</h3>


<form action="index.php" method="POST">
<input type ="text" name="Japanese">
    <input type ="submit" name ="Submit" value ="Submit">
</form> 

So right here the user types in their Japanese word and it sends it to the database and performs    the query.
```

On the same page, I have a second form that is suppose to send the action to lookup.php when an action has been clicked. This is now happening. It sends the query right to index.php. The code is:

```
<h3>Use the fieldboxs down below to Enter your Japanese words into your dictionary</h3>
<form action ="lookup.php" method ="post">
EnglishWord:<input type ="text" name="EnglishWord">
Japaneseword: <input type ="text"   name="JapaneseWord">
    <input type ="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

IS there a quick solution to this or am I forced to put this code on an entirely different page?

Comment: Is `lookup.php` in the same directory as this page?

Comment: It's difficult to follow what you're doing here or exactly what the problem is.  A page has two forms, and the user submits either one or the other, correct?  What's the issue?  Do you want the user to stay on the page without reloading it or something?  Do you want one submit action to go to two places?

Comment: From the description of your question I would have said you don't have a closing </FORM> tag on your first form, but I can clearly see the tag there in the code you provided.

Comment: Add a name attribute to **each** form and that should do the trick. ` <form name='first_form' action='index.php' method='post'>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a problem to have more forms on the same page. Since the script files handling each individual form  are doig their own stuff in the background and fetching data from their own form :)

Btw, you can use the same PHP file for handling both forms if you just use it like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['value1_from_form_1'],$_POST['value2_from_form_1'])) {
  // logic to process form 1 values
}

if(isset($_POST['value1_from_form_2'],$_POST['value2_from_form_2'])) {
  // logic to process form 2 values
}
```

This way PHP script will "fire" depending on which value pairs are sent, so if form 1 is submitted on the page, first code block fires and vice versa. You can also use one form to send GET and other to send POST data etc.

Comment: Just avoid putting all the controls in one form, or putting one of the forms inside the other. Also, make sure any Javascript you have referencing either of the forms uses ID values (or some other method of exclusion)